# Dynamic include with ASP.NET Web Pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

In [ASP.NET Web Pages/Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) is there a way to include a file, such as a Helper or something similar, without knowing it's name?

In Web Forms I do this by dynamically adding a User Control, like the code below, but am wondering if there is a way of doing something similar in Web Pages?

```
ContentTemplateBase control = (ContentTemplateBase)Page.LoadControl("~/ContentTemplates/" + detail.Template + ".ascx");
control.DataSource = detail;
plhTemplate.Controls.Add(control);
```

I know I could do this with a bunch of conditional statements, like...

```
if (detail.Template== "Template1")
{
    @MyHelpers.Template1(detail)
} else if (detail.Template== "Template2")
{
    @MyHelpers.Template2(detail)
} ... etc
```

...but wanting to do this without having to list all possible options.

Comment: do you want to add this some controll at first render or OnPostBack?

Comment: On first render, but to be clear this is Web Pages not Web Forms.

Comment: This isn't really a Web Pages problem. It's a coding/design problem. Whatever you want to do is most likely achievable. However, I doubt anyone here can help you achieve it based solely on the information you have provided.

Comment: On re-reading the Web Pages documentation I see I can use the RenderPage() method to include code from another file, so this seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On re-reading the Web Pages documentation I see I can use the [RenderPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpage.renderpage(v=vs.111).aspx)() method to include code from another file, so this seems to be the best option.